# Play! Framework and Comet with jsonp

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, comet

I am attempting to create a comet channel in my play 2.0 app.  When testing locally everything works well, unfortunately when deploying the code and using it i get the following message:

[16:03:24.195] Permission denied to access property 'cometfunc' @ http://dfc3379b64b6.v2.localtunnel.com/comet

which I believe is due to cross domain permissions.

Is this possible and if so what is the best way to fix the problem.  I believe it has to do with
val comet = Comet[String](callback = "parent.cometfunc") in my controller.  I have a second app that is my front end for other services which runs in a different domain and includes the javascript to connect to the comet socket.